# Updating UILabel in a loop?

Tags: objective-c

I want the screen to display the number on each iteration for the following example code??
This code shows the last iteration number regardless of using a pause...

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
}
```

I have updates coming across TCP Sockets in a while loop... only the last update gets written to the screen... and it is slow so I should see all the updates.

Comment: It's probably iterating too fast for you to see the changes.

Comment: What kind of behaviour are you expecting? Like a count up to 10 taking 10 seconds?

Comment: this is an example... i can put a pause in there... makes no difference

Comment: Can you clarify a little further, please? Also, is this happening on the main thread? All updates to UI elements must happen on the main thread.

Comment: The issue is that updates to the UI elements aren't actually made until the beginning of the next run loop, until the code you execute completes. So you can update the text property all you want but it will only take the last value unless you use NSTimer or dispatch_after. If you're looking for a rapidly increasing label that "flashes" from 0 to 10, use the solution below but with a small time interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set a timer to handle the update of your label. Right now the whole loop is happening in a fraction of a second.

```
NSTimer * aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimerLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)updateTimerLabel {
    static int i = 0;

    [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i++];
}
```

This way your label should get updated once every second.

Comment: This is right, but the problem isn't that it's happening too fast, it's that changes to the interface won't appear until control returns to the UI thread, in other words, until your code stops doin' stuff.

Comment: but he obviously doesn't care about that, the above code is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: If you have a while loop listening to TCP sockets it should be happening in a background thread dedicated to it, letting you update on your main thread the UI. However the code that you posted has nothing to do with that and it is becoming quite confusing.