# How to add UILabel from a loop?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uikit

Sorry for my english.

I want to display words separated in characters. i have different strings in "chars" array that contain single characters. i tried this one:

```
int x = 20;
int y = 20;
int screenx = self.view.bounds.size.width - 14;
for (NSString *string in chars){
    for (int i=0; i<messageLength; i++) {
        UILabel *display;
        display.text = [chars objectAtIndex:i];
        display.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 14, 22);
        display.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        x = x + 14;
        if (x >= screenx){
            x = 20;
            y = y + 20;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What was the result of this? Where are you having a problem?

Comment: Please ask your question in detail... what we understand by this code? what you want to find out???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically updating a UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6336991/), [Updating UILabel in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707388/updating-uilabel-in-a-loop/8707418#8707418)

Comment: Remove inner for loop & use
UILabel *display = [[UILabel alloc] init];
display.text = string;

Comment: the result was a black screen :(, the problem is that the uilabel that i create doesn't go on the view. and what i want is different labels with different characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually create the label and place it on your view.

```
UILabel *display = [[UILabel alloc] init];
display.text = [chars objectAtIndex:i];
display.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 14, 22);
display.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubView:display];
```